# OData SingleResult<object> method throws 404 error

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

My OData method looks like this. The first method works fine. But 2nd method throws 404 Not found error.

```
[EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Personal> GetPersonalDetailsFull()
        {
            return db.PersonalDetails;
        }

    [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<Personal> GetPersonalDetail([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            var data = db.PersonalDetails.Where(personalDetail => personalDetail.AutoId == key).AsQueryable();
            return SingleResult.Create(data);
        }
```

My web.config settings for handler looks like this

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/odata/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

When I am making request

http://localhost:56234/odata/PersonalDetailsFull - this works fine and gets all data

When I make http://localhost:56234/odata/PersonalDetailsFull(16), it says 404 NOT Found in fiddler and through client as well.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I tried different means but no luck. Wondering if handler is not accepting parenthesis "(16)", not sure. BUt the Path is "/odata/*" so this should not be issue.

Answer (score 0):

What's your entity type name? Basically, convention routing for request template 
`~/entityset/key` follows the following action name convention:

```
1. HttMethodName + entityTypeName
2. HttpMethodName
```

So, please make sure your second action name follows the #1 convention. Thanks.

Comment: My entity type name is "PersonalDetail" and I am calling my controller as "PersonalDetailsFullController"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. By mistake my WebApicConfig builder configuration was wrong.

instead of following 
builder.EntitySet("PersonalDetailsFull");

I had kept
builder.EntitySet("PersonalDetailsFull");

Sorry for bugging.

Thanks

Comment: Long shot as it was 4 years ago...but I am having this exact issue. Both of the lines from your builder you mention are the same. Do you remember was wrong?